# Python how to exit main function

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Terminating a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)
>   [Terminating a Python Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949504/terminating-a-python-program)

My question is how to exit out in Python main function? I have tried '`return`' but it gave the error `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    if condition:
    (I want to exit here) 
    do something
  finally:
    do something
```

Comment: WHen you searched what did you find?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+exit.  All of these seem  to have something in common.

Comment: I think people have missed the point of this question.  The OP is not looking for a generic way to terminate a program.  He wants to know why, in this case, `return` does not work for that purpose.

Comment: This answer to a related question seems the most useful here http://stackoverflow.com/a/953385/86967.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()` to exit from the middle of the main function.

However, I would recommend not doing any logic there. Instead, put everything in a function, and call that from `__main__` - then you can use return as normal.

Comment: +1 for adding an explicit 'everything' function. This also makes it easier to (1) call this script from other scripts (2) unit test.

Comment: Guido van Rossum supports (or at least, used to) this approach: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829

Comment: I typically create a function named "main" and put it at the top of the file.

Comment: exit() works fine for me, using python 2.7.x

Answer (score 37):

You can't return because you're not in a function.  You can `exit` though.

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

0 (the default) means success, non-zero means failure.

Comment: Why `sys.exit()` instead of just plain `exit()`?

Comment: Why not? Also, Python tries not to provide more built-in functions than are necessary.

Comment: @Just, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#exit) say not to use plain `exit` in programs, and it's arguably a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue8220) (albeit a WONTFIX) that you even can.

Comment: The exit() is defined in site.py and it works only if the site module is imported so it should be used in the interpreter only.

https://www.scaler.com/topics/exit-in-python/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/

Answer (score 14):

If you don't feel like importing anything, you can try:

```
raise SystemExit, 0
```

Comment: Can this be caught if someone wanted to extend the main and not exit at the end of it?

Answer (score 7):

use sys module

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `sys.exit`.